# Javascript code not working

Tags: javascript

The following code is not working. Want to check white spaces in an input field. If there are not any white spaces want to alert. Any help

```
<script language="javascript">
document.register.eventdtls.value;
function hasWhiteSpace(strg) {

var whiteSpaceExp=/\s+$/;

if (whiteSpaceExp.test(strg))
alert("Please Check Your Fields For Spaces");
      return false;
else
return true; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As a general hint: you might want to add what the code is supposed to do, what your input is, what you expect to happen and what really happens. That makes it easier for us to help you, no matter how simple or trivial you think your code might be. You also avoid your question being closed because it's "not a real question".

Comment: @kingfisher what error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing brackets:

```
if (whiteSpaceExp.test(strg)) {
    alert("Please Check Your Fields For Spaces");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current regex will only test for spaces at the end of the string (that's what the `$` represents here);

Your regex should be:

```
var whiteSpaceExp=/\s+/;
```

Also, you need to put brackets around your `if(){ } else{ }` because you have multiple statements.

```
function hasWhiteSpace(strg) {

    var whiteSpaceExp = /\s+/;

    if (whiteSpaceExp.test(strg)) {
        alert("Please Check Your Fields For Spaces");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: no its not giving any alert....document.form.field.value. is correct and placed right???

Comment: @Kingfisher Your question doesn't mention anything about the form field. Are you sure the string is being passed into the function correctly? The function I've given works. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/e2Ytx/

Comment: @Kingfished - How are you validating the input box? What event are you hooking the code on to?

Comment: @Kingfisher: If you mean `document.register.eventdtls.value;` then yes, it is valid, but you are not assigning the value to any variable, nor are you calling the function anywhere. I suggest to read a JavaScript tutorial first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript/guide

Comment: @Kingfisher: As said, read a tutorial first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript/guide

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Use braces in your 'if' statement

```
if (whiteSpaceExp.test(strg))
{
     alert("Please Check Your Fields For Spaces");
     return false;
}
else
return true;
```